# Merge two CreateView to show there forms in DetailView of post model

Tags: python, django

Forms are not shown. How should i show multiple forms in one page? I want to make writing comment & reply system.

Here is *comment.html*

```
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>COMMENT</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
          <h2>{{ object.text }}</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="comment-area">
           {% for comment in post.comment.all %}
              <div class="media m-3">
                 <div class="media-body">
                    <h5 class="mt-0">
                       <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">{% by_the_time comment.created_at %}</span>
                       {{ comment.name }}
                       <span class="lead text-muted">{{ comment.created_at }}</span>
                       <a href="{% url 'recomment' comment.pk %}"Reply</a>
                    </h5>
                    {{ comment.text | linebreaksbr }}
                    {% for recomment in comment.recomment.all %}
                       <div class="media m-3">
                          <div class="media-body">
                             <h5 class="mt-0">
                                {{ recomment.name }}
                                <span class="lead text-muted">{{ recomment.created_at }}</span>
                             </h5>
                             {{ recomment.text | linebreaksbr }}
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </div>
               </div>
           {% endfor %}
        </div>

        <form action="" method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
          {% for field in form %}
            <div class="form-group">
              {{ field.errors }}
              <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">
                 {{ field.label }}
              </label>
              {{ field }}
            </div>
          {% endfor %}
          {% csrf_token %}
          <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="comment">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

In *views.py*, I have three views

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
      model = Post
      template_name = 'comment.html'

class CommentCreateView(generic.CreateView):

    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentCreateForm

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['post_pk'] = self.kwargs['pk']
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        post_pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.target = Post.objects.get(pk=post_pk)
        self.object.save()
        return redirect('detail', pk=post_pk)

class ReCommentCreateView(generic.CreateView):

    model = ReComment
    form_class = ReCommentCreateForm
    template_name = 'comment.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        comment_pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        comment = Comment.objects.get(pk=comment_pk)

        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['post_pk'] = comment.target.pk
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        comment_pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        comment = Comment.objects.get(pk=comment_pk)

        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.target = comment
        self.object.save()

        return redirect('detail', pk=comment.target.pk)
```

in *urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('comment/<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(template_name='comment.html'), name='comment'),
]
```

When I access `http://localhost:8000/polls/comment/1/`, no form is shown. I think `CommentCreateView` & `ReCommentCreateView` class in views.py is not connected with any urls but I wanna show these forms are in comment.html. How should I do this?

Comment: your url is pointing to `DetailView` and there is no `form_class` attribute mentioned

Comment: @Satendra I wanna  make only one method which has functions of DetailView&CommentCreateView&ReCommentCreateView .So these classes use general class ,so I do not know how I can make my ideal method. How should I fix this?

Comment: check my answer, hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am assuming you want to create comment and reply(re-comment) on particular comment on detail page of `Post` model.

You can create a `View` inspite of creating a `CreateView` for  *CommentCreateView* and *ReCommentCreateView* class and override `post` method

```
class CommentCreateView(generic.View):

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      form = CommentCreateForm(request.POST)
      post = Post.objects.get(pk=kwargs['post_pk'])
      if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.target = post
        obj.save()
      return redirect('detail', pk=post.pk)

class ReCommentCreateView(generic.View):

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      form = ReCommentCreateForm(request.POST)
      comment = Comment.objects.get(pk=kwargs['comment_pk'])
      if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.target = comment
        obj.save()
      return redirect('detail', pk=comment.target.pk)
```

Now send `ReCommentCreateForm` and `CommentCreateForm` in context data of your *DetailView* class.

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'comment.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
       context['comment_form'] = CommentCreateForm()
       context['recomment_form'] = ReCommentCreateForm()
       return context
```

In your comment.html you can use both variable to render form.

```
# comment form action url should have id of post.
<form action="{% url 'comment' post_pk=post.id %}" method="post">
   {{comment_form}}
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="comment"> 
</form>

# re-comment form action url should have id of comment on which user is replying.
<form action="{% url 'recomment' comment_pk=comment.id %}" method="post">
   {{recomment_form}}
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="re-comment">
</form>
```

Update your urls for all views like below.

```
urlpatterns = [    
    # Detail page of post url 
    path('post/<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='post'),
    # CommentCreateView page url to create comment on post
    path('comment/<int:post_pk>/', views.CommentCreateView.as_view(), name='comment'),
    # ReCommentCreateView page url to create re-comment on comment
    path('recomment/<int:comment_pk>/', views.ReCommentCreateView.as_view(), name='recomment'),
]
```

> Access your post detail page using:
>   `http://localhost:8000/polls/post/1/`

Comment: thx ur answer.It is very helpful to me.But when I access http://localhost:8000/polls/post/1/,NoReverseMatch at /polls/post/1/
Reverse for 'recomment' with keyword arguments '{'comment_pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['app/recomment\\/(?P<comment_pk>[0-9]+)\\/$'] .
I wrote ur codes correctly,and no error happens in  1st form tag (# comment form action url ~),so I really cannot understand how I should fix this.What should I do to fix this?

Comment: have you changed url_pattenrs? as i have mentioned in answer

Comment: if this doesn't help, share your code in github, so that i can look into it and tell you what exactly you are missing.

Comment: Hey @user9179850 i made 2 changes, rest of code seems fine. i have sent you pull request in github, accept  it and take pull and let me know if this is working now, as you have changed your app name to `app` so you have to access detail page using `http://localhost:8000/app/post/1/`